# How do I check for emulated prepared statements in ADOdb?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, adodb

I've been using [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) for many years as my database abstraction and query caching layer. Lately I switched to prepared statements, mostly for security, and became curious about the way they are (or are not) implemented.

Quote from the documentation for the [Prepare](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#prepare) method: “**Returns an array containing the original sql statement in the first array element; the remaining elements of the array are driver dependent. If there is an error, or we are emulating Prepare( ), we return the original $sql string.**”

Testing the statement variable with:

```
$stmt = $db->Prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ?");
print_r($stmt);
```

On connections opened with ‘mysql’ or ‘mysqli’ parameter only the original query string is returned – meaning the prepared statement is emulated, I guess. A connection opened with ‘pdo_mysql’ returns (from print_r()):

```
Array (
    [0] => SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ? 
    [1] => PDOStatement Object ([queryString]=>SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ?) 
)
```

Can I take this as a definite proof of a real prepared statement? If not, does anybody know of a quick and dirty way to check server-side (something to look for in the query log, or maybe in MySQLProxy)? I tried to read the library source, but got lost halfway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I take this as a definite proof of a real prepared statement

As documentations says, if you try to prepare statement using driver that does not support prepared statements, only given query is returned, otherwise array with query as first element. So to check if prepared statement is going to be emulated just check if `$stmt` is array. I assume you wouldn't try to prepare by passing an array, so this one should be enough:

```
$stmt = $db->Prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ?");
if(is_array($stmt)){
    //prepared
}
else{
    //emulated
}
```

If you are confused why **mysqli** driver returns SQL despite [mysqli driver supporting prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), it's explained in line 662 of *drivers/adodb-mysqli.inc.php*:

```
// Prepare() not supported because mysqli_stmt_execute does not return a recordset, but
// returns as bound variables.
```

Comment: Well, I went on a testing binge setting up the query log in MySQL and trying different connections: the whole affair is messier than I thought! ADOdb with the pdo_mysql driver does indeed issue a PDO->prepare() instruction - it's PDO itsef that then emulates a prepared statement! It seems that the only way to have real PS is using native mysqli functions and giving up on SELECT *.